# How to subset S4 list with 5 "csANNO" elements

Tags: r, list, subset, r-s4

I would like to subset/filter peakAnnoList based on $width > 4000.Seems that it is not so easy from S4 list with many complex elements including Granges and IRanges object. Here is the code to generate peakAnnoList:

```
## loading packages
library(ChIPseeker)
library(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
txdb <- TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene
library(clusterProfiler)

files <- getSampleFiles()
peakAnnoList <- lapply(files, annotatePeak, TxDb=txdb,
                       tssRegion=c(-3000, 3000), verbose=FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you state exactly where you are having a problem? What `class` is `peakAnnoList` (if it's a `list`, what class are its elements)? What is the class definition of that class? (I.e. what is the result of `getClass(class(peakAnnoList[[1]]))`?

Comment: peakAnnoList is a list with 5 elements and each elements contains combination of "csAnno" and "GRanges" and some other objects. I would like to filter all 5 elements of peakAnnoList for width > 4000. Here is the position of width (peakAnnoList[[1]]@anno@ranges@width).  I can do that with only 1 elements of list by converting it to data.frame, but I would like to have it for all elements.

Comment: If you are able to write some function `f` that takes a list element and returns TRUE/FALSE based on whether that element meets the criteria, then if your list is called `x`, `x[sapply(x,f)]` should give you the subset you desire.

Comment: Actually I am rather new to R, but will try and see wether I can do that. Thanks.

Comment: peakAnnoList_selected <- lapply(peakAnnoList, function(i) as.data.frame(i)$width >4000)
With this code I can subset, but the result is a list with 5 elements and all other parts of list are gone. I would like to have all the information of list but only width> 4000.

Comment: I suggested you do `x[sapply(x,f)]` — you have done `lapply(x,f)` instead so all you got was a list of TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: @JDL 
I tried also sapply as you said but again getting error.
`peakAnnoList_selected <- peakAnnoList[sapply(peakAnnoList, function(i) subset(i)$width >4000)]`

Comment: based in your earlier comments, it looks like you want to try `peakAnnoList_selected <- peakAnnoList[sapply(peakAnnoList, function(i) as.data.frame(i)$width >4000)]`

Comment: I also tried that but it is not working. I really dont know what should I do here! but seems that nobody else also know how to do that. I have to process so many data from ENCODE and it is more than a week I am waiting for this piece of code.

Comment: could you post the results (or error messages) when you run the various things we have discussed here? It's easier to help if we can see what the errors are, rather than "it doesn't work". Thanks!

Comment: @JDL
When I run this code 
`peakAnnoList[sapply(peakAnnoList, function(i) subset(i)$width >4000)]`
I get  the following error:
`Error in subset.default(i) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default`

Comment: For this code:
`peakAnnoList[sapply(peakAnnoList, function(i) subset(i)$width >4000)]`

I get the following error ` Error in subset.default(i) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default `

Comment: you almost certainly don't want to be using `subset` --- `[]` is doing the subsetting for you here. Just replace `subset(i)` with `i` and see what you get.

Comment: @JDL
`peakAnnoList[sapply(peakAnnoList, function(i) i$width >4000)]`.
and the error `Error in i$width : $ operator not defined for this S4 class`

Comment: right, you need to replace `i$width` with however you get the width out of this particular object (perhaps it is `i@anno@ranges@width`)?

Comment: @JDL
Thanks for the help.